# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;playlist_entity_assets.play_list_id&#039

Tags: mysql, laravel

I use three tables playlists, entityAssets, and playlistEntityAssets. 
PlaylistEntityassets table has 2 columns playlist_id, asset_id referring to the other two tables. when I try to get data filter by playlist_id it gives me this error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'playlist_entity_assets.play_list_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `playlist_entity_assets` where `playlist_entity_assets`.`play_list_id` = 3 and `playlist_entity_assets`.`play_list_id` is not null)

this is my get method. even though my table has a "playlist_id" column. this query calls for the "play_list_id" column.

```
public function show($subdomain, $id) {
$universe = Auth::user()->getCurrentUniverse();
$playlist = PlayList::find($id);

    //return empty responce
    if( $playlist == null){
        return Response::json();
    }

    $playlistAssets = array();

    $playlistEntityAssets =  $playlist->playlistEntityAssets;

    foreach($playlistEntityAssets as $plEntityAsset){

        $asset = $plEntityAsset->entityAsset;

        $plAsset = ['asset' => $asset ];

        $playlistAssets[] = $plAsset;
    }

    return Response::json($playlistAssets);
}
```

I want to fitler all enityAssets data filter by playlist_id in the "playlistEntityAssets" table.

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PlaylistEntityAssets extends Model
{

```
protected $table = 'playlist_entity_assets';

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('asset');
}
public function universe()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Universe');
}

public function playlist(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Playlist', 'playlist_id');
}

public function entityAsset(){
    return $this->belongsTo('EntityAsset', 'asset_id');
}
```

Comment: Can you please add what code you have added in "playlistEntityAssets" ?

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed the problem. The answer is to put the exact column name in the playlist model.

```
class PlayList extends Eloquent{
  public function playlistEntityAssets()
 {
   return $this->hasMany('PlaylistEntityAssets', 'playlist_id' );
 }
}
```